# JQuery Option Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am a new bee using JQuery.

Both the statments  does the job for me. But I couldnt understand what the > symbol in first is doing??

```
$("#OrganiastionSettingsAll > option:selected");
```

And

```
$("#OrganisationSettingsAll option:selected");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `>` symbol specifies that the `option` tags have to be children of `#OrganiastionSettingsAll`, not descendants.

For example:

```
<div id="outer">
   <div>
     <span>Foo</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

`#outer span` matches the `<span>` tag, but `#outer > span` does not.

Answer (score 1):

P `>` C is used for descendants of first level where as `P` `C` for all levels down the hierarchy.
More specifically The child combinator (P > C) can be thought of as a more specific form of the descendant combinator (P C) in that it selects only first-level descendants, [**jQuery Doc**](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

`>`**chooses only first-childs.**
example

```
ul>li
```

selects only li that are direct children of an ul

```
ul li
```

selects all li elements within an ul

Answer (score 0):

The `>` means that the `option:selected` must be a child, or direct descendant of `#OrganiastionSettingsAll`. The example without the `>` means that `option:selected` can be a descendant at any level of `#OrganiastionSettingsAll`.

> The child combinator (E > F) can be thought of as a more specific form
>   of the descendant combinator (E F) in that it selects only first-level
>   descendants.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

`>` is for direct descendants in CSS selectors.

Picture the case

```
<div>
    <span>
        <strong>Hi!</strong>
    </span>
</div>
```

`$('div > strong')` will return zero elements, strong is not a direct descendant of the div.

`$('div strong')` and `$('div > span > strong')` will both return the strong element with text of "Hi!". The second selector uses the direct descendent operator while the first selector doesn't require that the strong be a direct descendent of the div.